# filter results based on user level CASE v. IF

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay I am having an issue with this.

I have 2 different tables that I am trying use to restrict access to records.

Users are based on 4 levels.
lvl 1 being the highest and lvl 4 being the lowest.

The users table has 7 fields.  The other table also has the fields below indicated by {train_...}

- userID (AI) Int
- ** UserLogin varchar
- UserPass Password
- UserEmail email varchar
- UserActive Y/N int
- ** UserAgency varchar
- ** UserComp varchar
- ** UserMSC varchar
- ** UserSubMSC int
- ** UserLevel int 
  ** indicates these are set to variables once the user signs in.

In my php code I have tried IF statements, and In my SQL I have tried CASE statements.

I cannot get the IF statement to function, as I keep getting a syntax error.  Parse Error: unexpected } on line ....

The CASE statement works for the SQL, however, it causes issues with dynamic searches once the form is loaded.

The If Statment  
[] are global variables and {} indicate field names.

```
if ('[usr_level]' == 1) 
{ 
    '{train_agencyID}' == '[agencyID]'
}
elseif ('[usr_level]' == 2)
{ 
    '{train_componentID}' == '[componentID]'
}
elseif ('[usr_level]' == 3)
{ 
    '{train_UnitMSC}' == '[mscID]'
}
elseif ('[usr_level]' == 4)
{ 
    '{train_Unit_Comp}' == '[submscID]'
};
```

The CASE Statement

```
WHERE '[usr_level]'
  CASE WHEN '[usr_level]' = 1 THEN 
    train_agencyID = '[agencyID]' 
  END
  OR
  CASE WHEN '[usr_level]' = 2 THEN
    train_componentID = '[componentID]' 
  END
  OR
  CASE WHEN '[usr_level]' = 3 THEN
    train_UnitMSC = '[mscID]'
  END
  OR
  CASE WHEN '[usr_level]' = 4 THEN
    train_Unit_Comp = '[submscID]'
  END
```

I've been racking my brain for 3 days now and I'm missing something simple but for the life of my I cannot figure this out.

Comment: It's been a long time since I have done any significant php; would that `};` cause a problem?

Comment: Your PHP makes no sense. Same for the SQL. What result do you expect? What is the point of assign different values to different vars/fields? With the SQL code, tables and columns should be quoted with a backtick. single quotes can work, but it makes the code more readable.

Comment: '{train_agencyID}' is a varchar field on the form.  the table column name is train_agecnyID. '[agencyID]' is a varchar global variable.    I want the script to check the records train_agencyID against the users [agencyID] and return only the records that match

Comment: `syntax error. Parse Error: unexpected } ` this is because the line before the first `}` has no semi colon. But as others have said, your PHP is not valid code so it wont work for many reasons.

Comment: This is the actual code without the pseudo code

    if ($usr_level == 1) 
    { 
        tbl1.train_agencyID == $agencyID
    }
    elseif ($usr_level == 2)
    { 
        tbl1.train_componentID == $componentID
    }
    elseif ($usr_level == 3)
    { 
        tbl1.train_UnitMSC == $mscID
    }
    elseif ($usr_level == 4)
    { 
        tbl1.train_Unit_Comp == $submscID
    }

Comment: @SloanThrasher.  The point is to limit results based on the user level.  The results that are returned sub reflect that of sub units within an organizaiton. i.e. The CEO can see all records, the HR department can see all records, but the north division can only see north division records, while the department manager of north division dept 3 can only see north division depart 3 records.

Comment: @IdontDownVote I'm attempt to verify that tbl1.train_agency is equal to $agencyID and return only the records were these two match.  I guess I should really get some sleep.

Comment: @IdontDownVote  tbl1.train_agecnyId is a column in table tbl1 named train_agencyID .  $agencyID is a varible set from tbl_users in a column named usr_agencyID.  the field is set as a varible during the login process.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you, here is a basic switch statement with php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_level"  />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php


$user_level = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_level');

switch($user_level) {
    case '1':
       $train_agencyID = 'agencyID';
        break;
    case '2':
        $train_componentID = 'componentID';
        break;
    case '3':
         $train_UnitMSC = 'mscID';
    case '4':
         $train_Unit_Comp = 'submscID';
         break;
         default:
         $error = "Invalid selection.";
    }

  if(isset($train_agencyID)) {
    echo $train_agencyID;
  }
  elseif(isset($train_componentID)) {
    echo $train_componentID;
  }
  elseif(isset($train_UnitMSC)) {
    echo $train_UnitMSC;
  }
  elseif(isset($train_Unit_Comp)) {
    echo $train_Unit_Comp;
  }
 ?>
```

I added more code so you can test this and see the output for yourself.

Comment: I will give it a try and see if I get any better results.

Comment: I apologize, I added the closing bracket.

Comment: The code is executing after fixing a couple of typos, however it is not filtering the results as intended.  My test db has 32 records and all 32 are being returned.

I'm going back the php manual again tomorrow... I am really lost on this... Only been working on php scripting for a few months here. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you are following what I am attempting to do. I need a condition that will filter based on a declared variable.  user table row 1 has the following data: `usr_level = 1, usr_agencyID = t101, usr_componentID = ACC, usr_MSCID = A19, usr_submsc = HHC`

`$usr_level, $agencyID, $componentID, $mscID, $submscID`

actual fields on the form and record table are those indicated above as `train_...`

If `$usr_level = 1` it needs to filter based on `train_agencyID = $agencyID`  If `$usr_level = 2` it needs to filter based on `train_componentID = $componentID`

Comment: Is it possible to see your form? I guess you are right, that I am not quite understanding what you need. You can use the above code to find their level...1, 2, 3, or 4. Once you find their $user_level then inside that block of case set your variables to what they should be dependent on their level.